# Collecting magical berries

Tags: c++, optimization, algorithm, programming-challenge

[Here is the link of the problem](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE13/problems/COLLECT) for which I need your help.

I came up with solution and it is working fine for all cases, but it takes more time. I need your help in reducing the runtime of code. I unable to optimised it more.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

long nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k )
{
    if (k > n) 
        return 0;
    if (k * 2 > n) 
        k = n-k;
    if (k == 0) 
        return 1;
    long result = n, temp;
    for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
        result *= (n-i+1);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int n,q,i,j,left,right;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cin>>q;
    string s;
    while(q--)
    {
        int b=0,r,q,re;
        long res=1;
        cin>>s >>left >>right;
        if(s=="change")
        {
            arr[left-1]=right;
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=left-1;i<right;i++)
            {
                b+=arr[i];
            }
            r=(right-left+1);
            q=(b/r);
            re=(b%r);
            res*=nChoosek(r,re);
            for(i=0;i<re;i++)
            {
                res*=nChoosek((b-(i*(q+1))),(q+1));    
            }    
            i=0;
            while((r-re-i) > 1)
            {
                res*=nChoosek(((r-re-i)*q),q);
                i++;
            }
                            res%=3046201;
            cout<<res<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to replace the function `nChoosek`

```
long nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k )
{
    if (k > n) 
        return 0;
    if (k * 2 > n) 
        k = n-k;
    if (k == 0) 
        return 1;
    long result = n, temp;
    for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
        result *= (n-i+1);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

By new recursive function ncr but no change in result:

```
long ncr(int n,int r)
{
    if((r==0)||(n==r))
        return 1;
    else 
        return (ncr(n-1,r-1)+ncr(n-1,r));
}
```

Comment: Not an optimization but a code style thingie: when testing `s == change`, if it is true, you could just `continue` instead of having `else`

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I will try to use it from now onward.But please tell me something about optimization. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One of the reasons they ask you to report the answer mod 3046201 is to prevent overflow errors. When you wait until the last moment to take the modulus, you frustrate that goal. If you had 100000 bushes with 30 berries each (as the problem statement permits), ncr would overflow.

Comment: When seeking to write fast code, you should first write clear code using the best algorithm possible. Then, if the code is not fast enough, run the code through a profiler to identify hot spots. Please profile your code (I like to use gperftools https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/). I suspect that ncr is going to be where your code spends most of its time and therefore where you should focus your effort.

Answer (score 3):

No optimisation so far but a few comments to make your code easier to read/improve :

1 Don't do ["using namespace std;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

2 Give your variables meaningful names.

3 Declare your variables in the smallest possible scope. Also, you should declare and define in the same times when it's possible. That would make things much easier (such as `int res = nChoosek(r,re);` instead of `res*=nChoosek(r,re);`).

4 Be consistent. You use `for(i=0;i<re;i++) {foo;}` and then, a few lines later `i=0; while((r-re-i) > 1){foo; i++;}`. Using another for loop would have have been a better option : `for (i=0; i<r-re-1; i++) {foo;}`

5 Enable the warnings in your compiler. A few weird things such as the useless statement in `for(i-0;i<n;i++)` should be detected.

6 Add a comment about the algorithm you've used.

Once this is done, we'll be in better conditions to start thinking about optimisations.

Comment: Thanks Josay, Your tips are really awesome. From now onward i will try to implement all your tips in my code. But one question for you : Why should i don't use "using namespace std;" ?

Comment: Glad you liked the tips. Please let me know when the next version of the code is to be reviewed and I'll try to have a look. As for the namespace question, my answer contains a link to a relevant SO question with interesting answers.

Comment: Hey josay, I edited the question according to your answer. The latest code you will find the in the below part of the question. Please let me know if we can optimize it.

Comment: There are still a few things I do find weird : `i-0` in the initialisation of the for loop for instance. Also, `string s` and `int berries` can still be defined a bit later in the logic.

Comment: Okay, i have edited my question according to your last comment.

Comment: Ok, I still see a fair amount of places where the comments are not taken into account : the `i` variable could be declared in the initialisation of most of the for-loops. Also as said before : `string s` and `int berries` can still be defined a bit later. This being said, if you want to work on performances, my advise would be to extract the computing logic taking the number of berries and the number of persons and put it in the logic on its own. Also provide some unit test for that method and optimisation can begin...

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistakes ( improper way of coding ).Here the link of program of variable declared accordingly. https://gist.github.com/Shravan40/5793959